# Linking problems using JsonCpp and Boost

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, jsoncpp

I have a project and I need to work with JsonCpp and boost/thread in VS2010
But I have a problem with linking:

- JsonCpp need to be compiled with runtime lib set to **MultiThread (/MT)**
- I think I have compiled boost/thread in static, MT because I have:

  - libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_48.lib
  - libboost_thread-vc100-mt-s-1_48.lib

Now, I have the following linking error:

> LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts
>     with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

If I use /NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRT, I have other linking errors...

Maybe I didn't compile boost correctly, I used their jam script with:

> runtime-link=static

Thank you :-)

Comment: Since you're using VS10, you could have installed Boost by using the [automated installer](http://www.boostpro.com/download/). :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to just include the JsonCpp source code into your project's source tree. For all of the disadvantages it may have, it works, and it's simple.

Comment: I used the Paul's solution, I didn't use the right compile line for boost. But the automated installer make it for me :)